# Align one element to left and one to the center of the screen and vertical align both - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have one list and a h1 header. I want the list to be on the left and the h1 to the center of the screen. Also I want the h1 to be vertical align to the middle of the list. The height and the width(will not be that big to overlap with the header. On smaller screens I will just put the list down the header) of the list is unknown. The h1 will be just one word. So the list determines the height of the container.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>BLOG</h1>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
   width: 100%;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul, h1{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I tried a various techniques especially with pseudo elements but to be honest I don't quite understand it and I am stuck a lot of hours with trying.

Sorry for my English

Reference :

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/14/justified-and-vertically-centered-header-elements/

Thanks in advanced.

**UPDATE**

Provided Layout Photo

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it by adding a couple of wrappers to your markup:

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="h1-outer-wrapper">
    <div id="h1-inner-wrapper"> 
      <h1>BLOG</h1>
    <div>
  </div>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul, #h1-outer-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#h1-inner-wrapper {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -.6em 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late response. Works great;